# Identifying CPU from lscpu command?

Tags: cpu

Does anyone have a clue what this CPU is? Here is the output from [`lscpu`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/lscpu.1.html):

[image]

Comment: I now know it's an Intel Xeon. But I don't know which one specifically.

Comment: Can't you just do `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, as there is a `model name` line?

Comment: Could you let us know the output from `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'physical id' | uniq`? It looks like the system might have multiple physical processors. Also, the configuration seems similar to [Xeon 7030](http://ark.intel.com/products/27225/Intel-Xeon-Processor-7030-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) but with 4 cores instead of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux lscpu provides basic information, however you can get greater details from the file /proc/cpuinfo.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

In the cases of multicore CPUs, each core will show up so you'll have a bunch of redundant information.  I have found it is quite often for the actual vendor model string to appear in cpuinfo, but not from lscpu.

[Example output](http://www.queryadmin.com/309/linux-cpu-architecture-information/):

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 15
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 11
cpu MHz         : 2405.424
cache size      : 4096 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 [...]
bogomips        : 4810.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

Comment: That won't work. Unless the CPU provides its brand string (P4 doesn't), youll see the exact same thing here the OP got with `lscpu`.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for the specific **CPU family** and **Model #** you should be able to determine the CPU.

From the information you've provided, your particular CPU belongs to Intel **Family 15**, with a model number of 4. These processors were designated with the **Prescott 2M** moniker ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_4_microprocessors)).

Some more information on the Prescott 2M core processors:

> Intel, by the first quarter of 2005, released a new Prescott core with
>   6x0 numbering, codenamed "Prescott 2M". Prescott 2M is also sometimes
>   known by the name of its Xeon derivative, "Irwindale".
>   [Source1](http://www.cpu-world.com/Cores/Prescott.html), [Source2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4#Prescott_2M_.28Extreme_Edition.29)

I'm having a bit of trouble determining the exact processor because of conflicting information. In the **Family 15, Model 4** list of processors, there doesn't seem to be one that matches the specifications in your post.

[A CPU family, model and stepping overview](http://www.jackcobben.nl/?p=2013) (search for "Family 15 Model 4")

Comment: That couldn't be true. The processor has 8 cores. P4 HT 620 only has one

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's a Prescott 2M CPU though. The processor is dual core, with hyper-threading.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is because the OP mentioned he knows it is a Xeon processor, just not which model it is. I'm inclined to think it's [E5-2650](http://ark.intel.com/products/64590) but there are just too many processors with 8 cores and similar GHz rating to say for sure. The BogoMIPS rating didn't help either.

Comment: Hmmm, that processor has 20MB of cache though (Not sure if that's L2 cache)

Comment: That's actually the L3 cache. The L2 cache size is 2048KB (8×256KB). The thing is, none of the eight core Xeon processors have a base frequency of 2.8 GHz (according to Wikipedia anyway). So if the `lscpu` output of 2.8 GHz is actually the 'Max Turbo Frequency' rating, it'll be tougher to identify the exact model. The easier solution would be to use CPU-Z or its Linux alternative, [i-Nex](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/nex-cpu-z-hardware-stat-tool-linux).

Comment: Maybe the `lscpu` command isn't outputting the correct information or wikipedia is missing some details (who knows?). Your suggestion is the best bet in that case. You should probably post that as an answer and explain why it's difficult to determine the CPU model from the lscpu command output.

Comment: @Vinayak Check again. The output is quite clear: 2 sockets, 2 cores, 2 threads.

Comment: @DanielB You're right. I incorrectly assumed `CPU(s)` to be the core count of the CPU. From what I gather from reading [this article about deciphering lscpu output](http://diego.assencio.com/?index=614d73283d49e939ebfb648cfb86819d), it looks like the processor is a quad-core Intel Xeon 2.8 GHz with 2 MB L2 cache.

Comment: No, it's a (well, 2) dual-core CPU with Hyperthreading enabled.

Comment: @DanielB Do you think there's more than one physical processors installed in the system?

Comment: @Vinayak Absolutely. The OP said it’s a Xeon, and `lscpu` says there are two sockets. 2 CPUs * 2 Cores * 2 Threads (Hyperthreading) = 8 Threads (AKA “CPUs”).

Comment: @DanielB If you've worked with a similar system with 2 or more physical CPUs, could you let me know if the L2 cache size reported by `lscpu` is the combined cache size of both the processors?

Comment: @Vinayak That I don’t know. Unfortunately, there are two CPUs matching here. One with 2 MiB L2 cache and one with 4 MiB. Figures. ;) With multicore CPUs, it’s per-core.